# Find the name of the duplicate folders and create a list with the path

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I try to make a textfile with path
To find duplicate folders/subfolders name inside a root path (for example I start from `Z:\METALAREA COLLECTION\`) I test with this

```
@echo ON
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R /D %%# in (*) do (
    echo "%%~n#">>"C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\text.txt"
)
```

and I get a textfile formatted in this very bad way

```
"A"
"# aggiornamenti"
"Abamath & Tahazu - Abamath_Tahazu [split]"
"Abamath & Tahazu - Abamath_Tahazu [split]"
"★"
"beta"
"★ Hekel - Waar de wind fluistert in de nacht, luister ik ★"
"★ Hekel - Waar de wind fluistert in de nacht, luister ik ★"

But I want a textfile formatted in this way

Abamath & Tahazu - Abamath_Tahazu [split]
Z:\METALAREA COLLECTION\ARCHIVE\A
Z:\METALAREA COLLECTION\# aggiornamenti

★ Hekel - Waar de wind fluistert in de nacht, luister ik ★
Z:\METALAREA COLLECTION\ARCHIVE\★
Z:\METALAREA COLLECTION\alfa\beta
```

Powershell solutions are good accepted because I have many folders with unicode or strange characters

Answer (score 0):

`dir /s /b /r /ad %root%` (why you using `/d`? okay I ignore it)

if `dosbatch` (but with `powershell`; you can try `cscript.exe` for vbs/wsh/jscript):

- make list (`dir /b /s /r /ad` & `tmpfile`)
- reverse characters (`powershell.exe`; unicode requires check [char] for 2 and 1 chars in cycle)
- sort.exe
- in cycle check `for /f %%s in ('type "tmpfile"') do set _t_s=%%s&call :sv_for_next`
- `:sv_for_next`  get `tmpv=%~1` from `call :argv_first "%_t_s:\=" "%"`
- check like `findstr /b /i /c:"%tmpv%\" | find /v "%tmpv%"` //it's contained '`:disk`' (secure)
- from ^step make list (`tmpfile2`) with folders for `tmpv` to print `tmpv` and directories after '`re-reverse`'

good luck )

also you can use stricted system (rules) for directories naming ("subdir" levels and/or another methods)